# Building a Dockerfile in DevOps pipeline

Tags: ibm-cloud, dockerfile

I've put a `Dockerfile` in the root directory of my project. I know the `Dockerfile` works because I've built it locally. But when I try to build it in the `pipeline`, it says `Dockerfile not found in project` and aborts.

The [documentation](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_single_pipeline_ov.html) indicates that it should work so long as the `Dockerfile` is in the root directory. So I'm really confused.

do I need to supply some additional information in the build job to point it do the `Dockerfile`?

Thanks.

Comment: Check my sample at: https://hub.jazz.net/pipeline/chemi/Demo4Bluemix%20(Docker) perhaps it can help you